# How does mdadm decide which disk to read from in mirrored arrays?

Tags: raid, mdadm

What exactly is the logic used to decide which block to read from diskA vs diskB in a mirrored array?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the answer](https://superuser.com/a/1611422/878373) to a similar question on superuser.com. It also links to the source code.